# Archive failed due to header not being found

Tags: objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to archive my app for submission, but I'm running into an error. In my app, I'm using the MBProgressHUD library, and the app works fine on the simulator, and all the devices I've tested on. However, when I go to Product > Archive, the build fails with the error saying:
`MBProgressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h` file not found."
Is there anything I had to do to prep the library? Any help would be appreciated, thanks!
~Carpetfizz

Comment: It seems when copied/added the library you did not add it to target. Just add it to your target and then archive.

Comment: @CodeMonkey thanks, but the issue was a lot simpler. Updated the question.

Comment: Oh well, without seeing your code I just tried to help. Glad you fixed it yourself. Please check your answer as the correct one so it will be removed from unanswered list. Good luck. :)

Comment: @CodeMonkey I'll keep your answer in mind if this happens again. Also, since I'm a relatively new user, it won't let me accept my answer as the correct one until two days, I will remember to do it once I'm allowed.

Answer (score 0):

I just had to change the MBPogressHUD/MBProgressHUD.h to just "MBProgressHUD.h" in my files.